# Android: Working with drive application folder

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm building application using Google Drive api. But app folder not working after uninstalling the app. Here is what I been trying to do:

```
public searchFiles(){
    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = getGoogleApiClient();
    Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(googleApiClient).listChildren(googleApiClient)
            .setResultCallback(metadataBufferCallback);
}

private final ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult> metadataBufferCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    // Error
                    return;
                }
                MetadataBuffer metadataBuffer = result.getMetadataBuffer();
                DriveId driveId = null;
                if(metadataBuffer.getCount() > 0){
                    Metadata metadata = metadataBuffer.get(0);
                    driveId = metadata.getDriveId();
                }
                metadataBuffer.close();
                if(driveId != null){
                    // success
                }
                else{
                    // omg, why?
                }
            }
        };
```

I am not working with filters just yet, I got only got one file there. If I replace `getAppFolder` with `getRootFolder` it works just fine.

Also it works when it's cached, but once I uninstall the application `metadataBuffer.getCount()` is always return `0`, even so in drive it says that I have 23 bytes of hidden data.

What am I missing here?

*I asked the user for `SCOPE_APPFOLDER` in the permissions. And I am running a signed version of the app.

Comment: Is this happening after you uninstall your app on your android device or when your unlink it from google drive?

Comment: @DeveloperPaul It's still linked. I just uninstall it.